# Implicit differentiation problem xy+4 = x

Tags: calculus

Can anyone show me how to solve this problem step by step, please?

Using implicit differentiation, what is dy/dx  if xy + 4 =  x?

I did f(x) = x 
g(x) = y 
f'(x) = 1
g'(x) = 1
(1)(y) + (x)(1) 
y'y + x + 4 = x

-4/y

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{d}{dx}(xy) = y + xy'$

Comment: My problem is I am not sure when to use a product rule, and chain rule. Is this need to use a product rule because of xy?

Comment: Yes, since $xy$ is a product. The Chain Rule is used when you have function composition, such $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \left(y^3\right) = 3y^2\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$. If you have something like $xy^3$, then you're going to use both.

Comment: You need the product rule for $xy$.

Comment: Can you update the question with your own attempt to solve the problem? Can you finish the problem after reviewing Fred's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ be the domain of $y$, hence

$$(*) \quad xy(x)+4=x$$

for all $x \in D.$ Observe that $ 0 \notin D$, why ?

From $(*)$ we get

$$ y(x)+xy'(x)=1$$

for all $x \in D.$

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Why downvoting ??

Comment: What does x∈D mean?

Comment: How can you get y(x) + xy'(x) = 1?
I got x + yy' = 1

Is this also using chain rule?

Comment: $x \in D$ means that we're looking at the domain only. For instance, there isn't an equality when $x = 0$ (clearly $4 \neq 0$). How exactly did you get $x+yy'$? Since you have a product, $(fg)' = f'g+fg'$, meaning $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (xy) = y\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (x)+x\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (y) = y\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dx}+x\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = y+x\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$, or written more compactly, $(xy)' = y+xy'$.

Comment: @KM101 Thank you for the explanation! I am still confusing x( 
I thought  (fg)′=f′g+fg′,  is (xy)' = 1 * y + x + 1 = x + y
Thus, d/dx (x) + d/dx (y) = 1
How did you get y and x in the front of d/dx(x) and d/dx(y) respectively you have explained?

Comment: $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (x)$ and  $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (y)$ simply mean $x'$ and $y'$. From $(xy)' = x'y+xy'$, $x' = 1$, as you correctly found, but why did you replace $y'$ with $1$?